Delta method confidence interval from 2SLS regression (with FE) using fixest and marginaleffects packages - Get NAs
I'm trying to find the confidence interval with the delta method using avg_comparisons() with the fixest feols() function for a 2SLS/IV + FE regression.
My specification has only one independent variable and one instrument. When I do my specification and I use avg_comparisons(), I get NAs.
Is there anything I can do to get the correct confidence interval?
One independent variable and one instrument example:
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)

TwoSLS <- feols(y ~ 0 | i + t | x1 ~ z, df)

avg_comparisons(TwoSLS)

Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error  z Pr(>|z|)  S 2.5 % 97.5 %
   x1 mean(+1)        0         NA NA       NA NA    NA     NA

predict(TwoSLS, newdata = head(df))

[1]  0.3466693 -0.7935570  2.3911069 -0.1111627 -1.1041513 -2.2443776

But it works when I add another independent variable, which is not what I really want:
TwoSLS_with_X2 <- feols(y ~ x2 | i + t | x1 ~ z, df)

avg_comparisons(TwoSLS_with_X2)

 Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S 2.5 % 97.5 %
   x1 mean(+1)    0.382     0.0876  4.361   <0.001 16.2  0.21  0.554
   x2 mean(+1)   -0.137     0.5007 -0.275    0.784  0.4 -1.12  0.844

predict(TwoSLS_with_X2, newdata = head(df))

[1]  0.4739496  0.2461527  2.3167039 -0.2782309 -1.1859796 -1.9779422

If anyone wants reproducible data:
i <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d")
t <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
y <- rnorm(16)
x1 <- rnorm(16)
x2 <- rnorm(16)
z <- rnorm(16)
n <- c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)
df <- data.frame(i,t,y,x1,x2,z,n)


You did not add just x2 in the second model, you also included an intercept. I don't know what all the pipes in these formulae mean but your first model looks like it's regressing y onto.. nothing. Is y ~ 1 the model you want there?

Hey, thanks for the reply! In feols(), y ~ 0 is the same as y ~ 1, and the results are identical. It's shown with the summary(), which states thats Dep. Var.: y, Endo. : x1, Instr. : z. Therefore, I am basically regressing y onto the instrument of X1 (with fixed-effects). When looking at the results of second model, I see X2 as an independent variable, and there's no intercept term.

Alright, apologies, in that case my comment only demonstrates my ignorance about what your model is actually doing.

You are getting this result because changing the x1 or x2 variable has no effect on the output of predict(). Consider what avg_comparisons() is doing under the hood (read tutorial here):
i <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d")
t <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
y <- rnorm(16)
x1 <- rnorm(16)
x2 <- rnorm(16)
z <- rnorm(16)
n <- c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)
df <- data.frame(i,t,y,x1,x2,z,n)

library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)

TwoSLS <- feols(y ~ 0 | i + t | x1 ~ z, df)

df_plus_one <- transform(df, x1 = x1 + 1)

pred <- predict(TwoSLS, newdata = df)
pred_plus_one <- predict(TwoSLS, newdata = df_plus_one)

all(pred == pred_plus_one)

    [1] TRUE

plot(pred, pred_plus_one)


Therefore, avg_comparisons() returns the correct estimate: a precise zero.

Thanks @Vincent for the reply. I clearly don't know how it works. I'll read about it and see if I can figure out how the other literature in my field gets the delta method standard error with just the specification.
